# Calendar sets alarm for next day

Tags: android, calendar

I'm working with Calendar. I use code below to set an alarm. But!!! If I try to set an alarm on Monday(Calendar.Monday) the actual alarm will be set on Tuesday. Why does this happen? I also tried to use `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())` but it didn't work.

And this is how I set an alarm for Sunday:

```
setAlarm(Calendar.SUNDAY, h, m, k, y);
```

My setAlarm() method:

```
public void setAlarm(int dayOfWeek, int hour, int minute, int position, int y) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyReceiver_Alarm.class);
        Long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), position , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
        Log.e("Point_1", "Time is " + calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you passing to the function as `dayOfWeek`?

Comment: @yogur I pass this setAlarm(Calendar.SUNDAY, h, m, k, y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 Sunday
1 Monday
2 Tuesday

DayOfWeek is **0-based**, and it starts from Sunday. 
So if you're passing 2, thinking that it's 1-based, you're getting Tuesday instead.

Comment: I pass Calendar."DAY OF WEEK" and not numbers.

Comment: Did you actually debug? What are the values you're getting? Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ?
alarmTime?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK starts from SUNDAY, so if u want to set alarm for monday set the value of int dayOfWeek to 2 . [refer image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgoYl.png)

Comment: I pass Calendar"DAY OF WEEK" as a parameter.

Comment: you can also use calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2); to set alarm for monday